# Skipping entering domain at login Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, authentication

Usualy domain users use there domain credentials (`firstname.lastname@domain.com`) to login to their SharePoint online (Office 365).

Now there are another users from another company (domain) which try to login to this SharePoint online. They have to use `firstname.lastname@theDomain.onmicrosoft.com` to be able to login successfully. Now they think the user name is too long and want to skip entering `@theDomain.onMicrosoft.com` somehow.

Is there a way to skip writing `@theDomain.onMicrosoft.com`?

I read [this article](http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/sso/358.using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx), however I think we need to have SSO on.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to share your site to external user where user can sign in with a Live-ID account instead. But that really depends on what your non-AD users are supposed to do in SharePoint Online? Document management is fine, but administration of Site Collection isn’t.

Ref: [Share sites or documents with people outside your organization](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to update the question because I think I didn't formulte the problem very well. The users are not external users. they belong to another domain and they must login using firstname.lastname@theDomain.onmicrosoft.com. I am trying to make a javascript file so that those users need to only enter their fristname.lastName and password. the javascript injects @domian.onmicrosoft.com and posts the form.

Comment: @Medes Ah! Ping me when you do, and I'll edit my answer as well :-)